# Suppose that $g: ℝ→ ℝ$ satisfies the following condition

Tags: real-analysis

$|g(x) − g(y)| ≤ (x − y)^2$  with $x,y ∈ ℝ$. Show that $g$ is constant. I think that I can divide by (x-y)^2 and analyse two cases, when the expression is greater than zero and when is less than zero. Thanks you!

Comment: Divide by $x-y$ and take the limit as $x \to y$. On the right you get zero, on the left you get the derivative of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert\le (x-y)^2$ for $x,y\in \mathbf{R}$. Assume that $x\ne y$, then dividing through by $x-y$ we have 
$$ \frac{\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert}{ x-y}\le x-y $$
if $x>y$ and
$$ \frac{\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert}{x-y}\ge x-y$$
if $x<y$. 
In the first case, taking the limit as $x\to y$ on both sides we have 
$$ 0\le\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert}{x-y}=\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert}{\lvert x-y\rvert}\le 0.$$
So, $\lvert g'(x)\rvert=0$. In the second case, we have
$$ 0\ge \lim_{x\to y}\frac{\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert}{x-y}\ge0.$$
In both cases, we have that $g'(x)=0$. This gives us the necessary result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show:  $g'(a) = 0, \forall a \in R$. So you would need to relate the left side with derivative of $f$ at $x = a$. So put $x = a+h, y = a \implies x - y = h \implies \left|\dfrac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}\right|\le |h|$. Let $h \to 0$, you get: $|g'(a)| = 0\implies g'(a) = 0$. Since this is true for any $a$, $g$ is constant.